Multiple or different indices
I am trying to write a report with different indexes, within the same document, I need to put an index, change the page and put a new index, that is, the new index begins with a new count of sections and subsections.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

welcome! please provide code for a minimal example demonstrating your setup. you have not even told us which format you're using. latex? plain? context? we also need to know your class (if latex) and possibly language(s). again, if latex, are you loading any index-related packages? imakeidx? index? splitidx? do you need unicode sorting?

actually, do you mean an index or something else? an index is a list of key words, symbols etc. at the back of a document with page numbers showing where the word or symbol is defined and/or used. it is sometimes split into groups e.g. symbols, A, B, C, ... but I've never seen one with numbered sections. do you mean you need multiple tables of contents?
